# css margin first or padding first?

Tags: css, stylesheet, margin, padding

In CSS code,

we use

```
#testing{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

i use [RECESS](http://twitter.github.io/recess/) to code qualify my css file

it suggest me to use **padding first and margin after**

```
#testing{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

My question is, does the order of padding and margin important in css quality?

And what's the different between padding first and margin first?

**EDIT**

just wondering why it suggest the order for me

[image]

Comment: As i know, it doesn't matter =\

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

Comment: I think First of Margin and than Padding

Comment: but i think it should not effect on the code if we will change the order of margin and padding....because however we will use margin padding it will in both cases....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, does the order of padding and margin important in css quality?

I consider the reason is **"coding style"**.

In order to readability, consistency, manage,  <del>picky</del>...

You can also order by a-z, type, css3 last...etc.

> And what's the different between padding first and margin first?

Looks.

**Example:**

> [WordPress CSS Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/#property-ordering)
>
> [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Declaration_Order)

Answer (score 1):

`Margin` is applied to the `outside` of you element hence effecting how far your element is away from other elements.

`Padding` is applied to the `inside` of your element hence effecting how far your element's content is away from the border.

Also, using `margin` will not affect your element's dimensions whereas `padding` will make your elements dimensions (set height + padding) so for example if you have a 100x100px div with a 5px padding, your div will actually be 105x105px

Answer (score 1):

The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around HTML elements, and it consists of: margins, borders, padding, and the actual content from top to bottom.

i.e. immediately on top content it takes padding value, border and finally on top of everything margin would come.

Margin,padding and border values should be deducted from the width before assigning the width value in css. For example `width: 100px, padding: 10px, margin: 10px, border: 5px` means width of the total container is 150px(100px+20px (left and right padding each 10px) + 10px (left and right border 5px each) + 20px (left and right margin)).

order of giving padding and margin values doesn't make any difference. we can write in any order in css.